CMakeLists.txt for Qt @ {wasm_singlethread, gcc_64}
Trying to build a trivial Qt (6.3.7) application,
(say one Window with one Button)
that can run both:

in host (gcc_64)
inside web-browser (wasm_singlethread).

Can someone please give or reference a small CMakeLists.txt
to be written and used without Qt-Creator.
Just with command lines like:
  emmake cmake && emmake make

